# auto-completion in MATLAB with nodesktop option

Tags: matlab, cmd

I'm using MATLAB R2012b on a win7 computer.
When I launch MATLAB from cmd using `matlab -nodesktop`, the `tab` is disabled for auto-completion in command line window. So I have to type the full name of a file, a path or a function.
When I open GUI and set as this link says, (http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/avoiding-repetitive-typing-with-tab-completion.html) auto-completion works fine in GUI. But it doesn't work when `-nodesktop` option is used.

I used to use R2014b on a Ubuntu machine with `-nodesktop` option, the auto-completion function works fine.

Is there any way to enable auto-completion in cmd when `-nodesktop` is chosen.

Comment: My guess is that this kind of 'fancy' behavior is GUI-only.

Comment: Thanks A. Donda. Actually, when I use non-GUI on Ubuntu, the auto-completion works fine. I expect MATLAB to be better compatible with Windows than Ubuntu.

Comment: Interesting. Makes sense to me, since on Linux we have full-fledged terminal emulators, while `cmd` is a hack. I don't now, maybe there are better character-oriented shells for Windows?